# Magento : add custom php code into product description

Tags: php, magento, product

I wrote a php script that resizes jpeg images provided by external URL.
The script works well on my server with a test page, but it seems that Magento doesn't allow custom php code into product description.

Is there any way to insert that piece of code into description ?

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$url_A = 'http:/...';
$url_B = 'http:/...';

$resizer_URL = 'http:/...';

echo '<a href="'.$url_A.'" target="_blank"><img class="scanA" src="'.$resizer_URL.'?url='.$url_A.'"/></a>
      <a href="'.$url_B.'" target="_blank"><img class="scanB" src="'.$resizer_URL.'?url='.$url_B.'"/></a>';

?>
```

The script code is:

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = $_GET['url'];

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio = $height / $width;

$new_width = 580; 
$new_height = $new_width * $ratio;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 75);

//
imagedestroy($image_p);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The most probably it's impossible. Why don't you use native magento image resize?

Comment: Cause i need to scale an external image (from imageshak host). Do you know any trick to achieve this purpose ?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the description file in your template? (/app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml)